# Need to sort DATE column by time (seconds) in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to sort the table by time using a `DATE` column in ORACLE DB

I know the question is silly, but I need to get the result set in chronological order which means latest record by second should appear first.

This is the column which needs to be sorted by seconds:

```
COLUMN NAME    DATA_TYPE
ID             NUMBER         
MESSAGE        VARCHAR2(4000)    
CREATED_DATE   DATE
```

In the below result, `textB` is inserted recently, so I want textB to appear first:

```
1    textA      31-AUG-17
2    textB      31-AUG-17
```

The Sad part is I can't change the column type from `DATE` to other.

Comment: `ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC`, at the end of your query.

Comment: of course it is possible: `ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC`. I'm curious why didn't you try it?

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC`

Comment: share data from your database for datetime field

Comment: Show us all columns, and how to order...

Comment: The record with same dates needs to be sorted by time

Comment: well, then in what column do you have that information?

Comment: Then ORDER BY CREATED_DATE DESC will work

Comment: If your column only stores the date part, you can't order by seconds.

Comment: `timestamp` is the ANSI SQL data type for date with time.

Comment: if you don't have that data, then you can't order by it. If you have another column with an autonumeric or something like that, then you can use that column for you `ORDER BY`. Otherwise, you simply can't

Comment: What about `ORDER BY CREATED_DATE ASC, ID DESC`?  Based on your example that `textB` was inserted more recently and therefore should be ordered first, I think this is the only way you will achieve that.

Comment: What database product are you using? @joelcoehoorn tagged your post as `oracle` but you mention DATE to DATETIME data type change; that is not Oracle!

Comment: @mathguy The `to_char()` function posted by the OP is his answer is Oracle-specific.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Right, and the reference to `DATETIME` data type in a comment by the same OP is (non-Oracle)-specific, which is why I asked. Clearly people are confused; I guess Magnus is not talking about Oracle when he says the `date` data type does not store information about seconds. (Initially I downvoted his answer for that reason, but then I realized when he posted the answer, the `oracle` tag wasn't there yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Oracle11g and with the following test data, it recognizes which data has been inserted recently even without the time.

```
CREATE TABLE t_date
(id NUMBER,
 message VARCHAR2(10),
 created_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO t_date VALUES
(1,'textA',TO_DATE('08/31/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'));
INSERT INTO t_date VALUES
(2,'textB',TO_DATE('08/31/2017 03:31:15','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO t_date VALUES
(3,'textC',TO_DATE('08/31/2017 01:31:15','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO t_date VALUES
(4,'textD',TO_DATE('08/31/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Query 1

```
SELECT id, 
       message, 
       created_date, 
       TO_CHAR(created_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') created_datetime
  FROM t_date;
```

Result 1

```
        ID MESSAGE    CREATED_D CREATED_DATETIME   
---------- ---------- --------- -------------------
         1 textA      31-AUG-17 08/31/2017 00:00:00
         2 textB      31-AUG-17 08/31/2017 03:31:15
         3 textC      31-AUG-17 08/31/2017 01:31:15
         4 textD      31-AUG-17 08/31/2017 00:00:00
```

Query 2

```
SELECT id, 
       message, 
       created_date, 
       TO_CHAR(created_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') created_datetime
  FROM t_date;
 ORDER BY created_date DESC;
```

Result 2

```
        ID MESSAGE    CREATED_D CREATED_DATETIME   
---------- ---------- --------- -------------------
         2 textB      31-AUG-17 08/31/2017 03:31:15
         3 textC      31-AUG-17 08/31/2017 01:31:15
         4 textD      31-AUG-17 08/31/2017 00:00:00
         1 textA      31-AUG-17 08/31/2017 00:00:00
```

See that id 1 and 4 have no exact time but were sorted descending in Query 2. So, if all your records were inserted with created_date has no exact timestamp, then ORDER BY DESC will suffice your requirement

Comment: This is because that's how it was stored on disk relative to the primary key: it works out by accident. However, plenty of things can cause the SQL engine to ignore this, like JOINing with a larger table where the primary key orders differently, or use in a LATERAL join or CTE, or any number of things. It's never a good idea to rely on the natural record order producing a consistent result order if that order actually matters.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, the `CREATED_DATE` DATE column already includes info down to the second. All you have to is order by that column:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
ORDER BY CREATE_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Unless... are you trying to get info by time of day?

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution for this which worked for me by using below.

```
select id
,MESSAGE
,CREATED_DATE
,to_char(CREATED_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') date_with_time 
from table_name
order by date_with_time desc;
```

I converted by using to_char and sorted.

Comment: This can't possibly actually work the way you want. All you've accomplished to list midnight (00:00:00) as the time value for every record. Even worse, your sort operation is looking at months first, so when sorting descending March 2016 records will appear before January 2017, which is not at all what you asked for.